# How to make certain functions for different roles in one command?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make that when using the command for the specified roles, a certain function is performed, for example, when a member with a first-level role uses the command, he will be given so much money, if a member with a level 2 uses the same command, he would be given a different amount of money, and so on with other roles.

Code:

```
module.exports = {
    cooldown: 1,
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder().setName("test").setDescription("test"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const guildId = "1115972333480452146";
        const userId = interaction.user.id;
        const itemId = "1116763689014398798";
        if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(`1115972503597228112`)) {
            const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder().setColor(0x0099ff).setDescription("У вас нет требуемого уровня добычи нефти.");
            message = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
        } else {
            const min = Number("10000");
            const max = Number("15000");
            var rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
            const exampleEmbed2 = new EmbedBuilder().setColor(0x0099ff).setDescription(`Вы получили ${rating}`);
            message = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed2] });
            const inventoryItem = await unb.addInventoryItem(guildId, userId, itemId, rating);
            console.log(inventoryItem);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: And what's not working, what did you try to fix the issue? Error codes?

Comment: @Kevin M. Mansour I tried to just copy the if function and paste it after the previous function, changing the text and role id

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code to make use of an object, `roleAmounts`, which will point to the `min` and `max` for any role IDs you have. `roleAmounts` is indexed with role ids, you will have to fill in the data for the remaining roles.

Next, check if the member has any of the roles in `roleAmounts` at all. If not, send the embed and `return`.

The rest is generally the same, deconstruct the `min` and `max` from the matching object in `roleAmounts` and pass it into `randomInt()` to get your random rating.

```js
// Define any constant values outside the execute() function, they do not need to be defined every time the command runs.
const itemId = "1116763689014398798";
const guildId = "1115972333480452146";
const randomInt = (min = 0, max = 0) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};

const roleAmounts = {
    'roleId1': {
        min: 10_000,
        max: 15_000,
    }

    // And so on...
};

module.exports = {
    cooldown: 1,
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("test")
        .setDescription("test"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const userId = interaction.user.id;

        // Return a matching role ID if the member has one
        const memberRelevantRoleId = Object.keys(roleAmounts)
          .find(roleId => interaction.member.roles.cache.has(roleId));

        if (!memberRelevantRoleId) {
            const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor(0x0099ff)
                .setDescription("У вас нет требуемого уровня добычи нефти.");
            return void await interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
        }


        const { min, max } = roleAmounts[memberRelevantRoleId];
        const rating = randomInt(min, max);
        
        try {
            // Ensure the function succeeds before sending a success message to the member
            const inventoryItem = await unb.addInventoryItem(guildId, userId, itemId, rating);
            console.log(inventoryItem);

            const exampleEmbed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor(0x0099ff)
                .setDescription(`Вы получили ${rating}`);
            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed2] });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
         
            // Do some error handling here
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: when I use the command it gives me an error: Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.

Comment: The code I posted will only reply to the interaction once. Either you added/changed the code, or the error is occurring in a different file. Check the stack trace to see where the error comes from